# Is there a way to obtain two separate strings from a single Input... disregarding whitespace in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For instance I have a `_dict` with an earlier piece of code checking whether the user input is in the dictionary.

```
rune = input("Please enter the Rune(Enter SKIP if none): ").lower()
if rune in _dict:
  rune = _dict[rune]
```

But is there a way to check for two entries from the single input? I can't use `.split()` because the user input already allows for a space... e.g `'pa vit'` is already in the dictionary, so split would return `'pa', 'vit'.`

I tried thinking of a way to check for a prefix or something in the input like if the user entered `pa vit + ra vit` it would split at the + not at the space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of the original input and each of the fragments:

```
for r in [rune] + rune.split():
    if r in _dict:
        r = _dict[r]
        break # Found; no need to split!
```